# Grafana data links do not refresh when tables are re-ordered

Tags: grafana

I'm using *Grafana 7.5.2*. I have a table with data links to another dashboard

> ```
> A B
> x 1
> y 2
> ```

Column `A` has a data link defined as `http://foo/${__data.fields.A}`
so *x* links to `http://foo/x` and *y* links to `http://foo/y`

If I now sort column `B` descending then the table now looks like

> ```
> A B
> y 2
> x 1
> ```

but the data links don't get refreshed, so now *y* links to `http://foo/x` and *x* links to `http://foo/y`

Is this a known issue?